# how to parse the href in a specific table?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Consider the wikipedia page about the list of countries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)

[image]

I am trying to parse the hyperlinks of the `Region` columns only. That is, for the value `Americas` I only care about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americas. I can successfully parse the table using

```
import requests
fullwiki = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)')
parsed = BeautifulSoup(fullwiki.content)
table = parsed.find('table')
```

but I am not able to extract this precise column (and its hyperlinks).

For instance, looking at the `a` tags can easily return **all** the hyperlinks, but how to find the ones in the column Region (assume you cannot cheat and use the hyperlink text to filter the hyperlinks)?

```
table.find_all('a')
 <a href="/wiki/Bethesda,_Maryland" title="Bethesda, Maryland">Bethesda, Maryland</a>,
 <a class="external text" href="https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:HWM" rel="nofollow">HWM</a>,
 <a href="/wiki/Howmet_Aerospace" title="Howmet Aerospace">Howmet Aerospace</a>,
 <a class="external text" href="https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=HWM&amp;action=getcompany" rel="nofollow">reports</a>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: i dont know how to do it. can you? thanks

Comment: if you've got the table, then you can ignore everything apart from the 2nd column, then you don't even have to bother to search by the `a` tag

Comment: yes, but parsing the table with pd.read_html for instance will not return the href... only Americas

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ below you should have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can try :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

fullwiki = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)')

soup= BeautifulSoup(fullwiki.content,"lxml")
# "lxml" is the parser you may use other parser. As far I know lxml is faster then other so I have used it.

trs = soup.find('table',class_="mw-datatable").find_all("tr")
# "mw-datatable" is the class name if the table you want to find from that link.
# There are multiple tables so by using specific table class name it select the table that we want

lst=[]
for tr in trs[2:]:
    tds=tr.find_all("td")
    link=f'https://en.wikipedia.org{tds[1].find("a")["href"]}'

    if link not in lst : # To don't take duplicate links, if you want all of links then
        lst.append(link) # You may remove all these IFs and write this line only.

    if len(lst)==5: # To don't literate unnecessary after getting all links 
        break

print(lst)
"""
['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americas', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe',
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceania', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa']
"""

df=pd.DataFrame({"Region":lst})

print(df)
"""
                                   Region
0  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americas
1      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia
2    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe
3   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceania
4    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa
"""
```

This will give you 5 links from region column in `DataFrame` as shown in output.

Comment: if that's the case, then it's problem of the source website than this code  garbage in = garbage out

Comment: by multiple times do you mean that there are a total of 7 distinct links there, but they are repeated over 100 times? if yes, might be OP is using this code somewhere else?

Comment: thanks, I only care about the hyperlink. in the example we only have 7 distinct ones but that's okay.

Comment: thanks! just a quick question, why did you you chose `lxml` here and how did you come up with the `mw-datatable`?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I have updated the answer, please check and inform me. If you understood all part clearly, and additionally if you don't want dataframe then you may remove those part. I believe you have somewhere mentioned about it so I provided it in answer.

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I believe we can remove mess like unnecessary comments.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = [x['href'] for x in soup.select('td[style="text-align:center"] a')]
    pp(goal)


main('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)')
```

Output:

```
['/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Asia',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Europe',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Africa',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Oceania',
 '/wiki/Americas',
 '/wiki/Oceania']
```